# JAXB polymorphic type object marshalling like Jackson

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson

I use Jackson to create JSON for polymorphic objects using an annotation in the ancestor class:

```
// Include Java class name ("com.myempl.ImplClass") as JSON property "class"
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")
```

Using this annotation, the descendant classes will have the `class` property with the class name of the object. This class name will be used when Jackson converts back JSON object to the correct descendant.

When using JAX-B with

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Class1, Class2, ... ClassN })
```

annotation, you have to specify all the subclasses of the element if you want correct unmarshalling, or you should add all elements to the `JAXBContext`, when creating a new `JAXBContext` instance.

Is there a way to specify the object class name to JAX-B just like with Jackson?
If there's no way, why?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the `@XmlType` annotation.  Below is an example of how it can be used:

### Java Model

**Root**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private List<AbstractClass> classes = new ArrayList<AbstractClass>();

    @XmlElement(name="class")
    public List<AbstractClass> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

}
```

**AbstactClass**

We will use the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation to cause `Class1`and `Class2` to be processed when the metadata is being figured out.  Java does not provide a mechanism to reflectively access the subclasses for a class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso({Class1.class, Class2.class})
public class AbstractClass {

}
```

**Class1**

By default each class has a class indicator name derived for the short class name.

```
public class Class1 extends AbstractClass {

}
```

**Class2**

We can use the `@XmlType` annotation to override the class indicator name.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name="class-two")
public class Class2 extends AbstractClass {

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

Below we will create an instance of `Root` and set instances of `Class1` and `Class2` on the `classes` property which is of the super type `AbstractClass`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.getClasses().add(new Class1());
        root.getClasses().add(new Class2());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

The value for the `xsi:type` for the instance of `Class1` was derived from the class name, and the value for the instance of `Class2` corresponds to the name we set on the `@XmlType` annotation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <class xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="class1"/>
    <class xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="class-two"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a solution to avoid listing the objects with @XmlSeeAlso({Class1.class, Class2.class}) or when creating the context. I store the className of the object in a variable. I wanted to know if there's a way to use it when unmarshalling the object instead of listing the classes.

Comment: I've ended up with creating a JAXBContext and using Guava to list all classes in a package to avoid manual class listing on the annotation.